# Where to find code coverage on Cypress dashboard

Tags: automated-tests, cypress

Where can we find Code coverage on Cypress dashboard? I find it hard to believe that it won't be there but also I don't see it anywhere.

Anything I need to do in the tests to see it on Cypress dashboard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know the dashboard doesn't integrate with code-coverage yet. There were some promises that this will be possible in the future, but for now the code-coverage reports are only available by default on CI level, usually as build artifacts, or integrated into pull requests: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/tooling/code-coverage#Videos

Comment: Thanks for your comment. That's a bummer. Although I do not see it in the pull requests either. can you share how could it start showing up there?

Comment: You can take a look at this video how they do it: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/tooling/code-coverage#Checking-code-coverage-on-pull-request
It isn't there out-of-the-box, you have to configure your server adequately, which might not be a trivial task.